# Is a standard pdf $f_Z(z)$ a member of its own scale family?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm having some misunderstanding about a result concerning ancillary statistics. To explain my confusion, let me provide a definition and a fact.

**Definition:** Let $f_Z(z)$ be any PDF. Then the family of PDFs of the form $f_X(x | \sigma)= \sigma^{-1} f_Z(x/\sigma)$, indexed by the parameter $\sigma$ where $\sigma >0$ is called the *scale family with standard PDF $f_Z(z)$*, and $\sigma$ is called the *scale parameter* for the family. We could denote the collection of PDFs forming this family by $$S(f) = \{f_X(x| \sigma) : f_X(x|\sigma) = \sigma^{-1} f_Z\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right), \sigma >0\}$$

The result that I'm failing to fully grasp is the following:

**Fact:** Suppose that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d from $f_X(x | \sigma)$, where $\sigma >0$, and that $f_X(x | \sigma)$ belongs to a scale family with standard pdf $f_Z(z)$ and scale parameter $\sigma$. Let $S(X)$ be a scale-invariant statistic; i.e., $S(x)$ satisfies 
$$S(dx_1, \ldots, dx_n) = S(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$$
for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$, and $d>0$. Then $S(X)$ is an ancillary statistic.

> My question is this: Is $f_Z(z)$ a member of its own scale family? If so, then what is the point of requiring that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution that is a member of a scale family? Why not just say that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ is a random sample from an arbitrary distribution?

Answer (score 1):

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancillary_statistic),

> An ancillary statistic is a measure of a sample whose distribution
>   does not depend on the parameters of the model.

The theorem states that a scale-invariant function of the sample has a $\sigma$-independent distribution. Without a scale parameter, we have no parameters with which to discuss a statistic's ancillarity, so it would be [vacuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).